# Как хранить и инициализировать общие для всех экземпляров класса строки?

Tags: c++, static, c++17

Как лучше хранить и инициализировать константные строки, которые являются общими для всех экземпляров класса?

- `static const std::string str;` объявление в классе (его объявление в хедере), определение `const std::string Class::str = "string";` в .cpp файле.
- `static inline const std::string str = "string";` в классе (определение в хедере)
- `const std::string str = "string";` в классе, потому что так можно cловить исключения в конструкторе в отличие от `static`
- `static constexpr auto str = "string"sv;` в классе, потому что можно использовать в constexpr контексте (но нужно преобразовывать в `std::string` в нужных местах)
- `static constexpr auto str = "string";` аналогично предыдущему
- какой-то другой способ (например, использовать статические функции с локальными статическими строками для отлова исключений)

Comment: Что значит "лучше"? Приведенные варианты не являются альтернативами.

Answer (score 0):

Как хотите, так и храните. Но `static` явно лучше, чем создание экземпляра строки для каждого экземпляра класса. Всё зависит от того, как у Вас эти строки используются. Если они везде используются как `std::string`, то логично их сразу создавать экземплярами этого класса, если как указатели, то создавайте указатели.

Использовать `std::string_view`, с моей точки зрения, не имеет смысла и попросту опасно. Этот тип для параметров функции, во всех других местах он создаёт больше проблем, чем решает.

> в классе, потому что так можно cловить исключения в конструкторе в отличие от

Это замечание вообще смысла не имеет, какая Вам разница где Вы словите `bad_alloc`? Вы что-то можете с ним сделать?

Между первыми двумя разница сугубо стилистическая, я бы выбрал второй вариант — писать меньше.